# current_user available in an observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, observers

OK, so I know this has been brought up before, and I realise that this breaks the MVC model in a purists view. However, I really think that things such as current_user or current_tenant should be available in an observer.

My specific case is that after actions have been done on a subset of my models (about half a dozen) I want something to be written to an audit log that includes the user that made the change and the tenant that made that change as well.

The first way to do this is to add a line to each controller method that carries out that function. To make this DRYer the actual activity is carried out in the application controller or the auditlog model and a simple one line statement is called from the controller. However this still means adding in the line, which isn't great and would be a whole lot more elegant if it were done in an observer.

However since an observer has no way of knowing what current_user is, this isn't possible. I've seen some work around using Thread, but these do not look that safe to me.

Now if anyone does have a more elegant solution, I'd love to hear it. Otherwise this is my case that we should have access to some controller methods in an observer. I'd like to get a sense of the feeling out there before putting this to the rails core dev team.

Comment: Can't you pass the current_user object to the observer somehow? It will be a workaround, but could give you the result you need

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how observers work, or to my knowledge anyway. They are just like model callbacks and so are triggered 'automatically' and can not have variables passed to them

Comment: Yes, but from our work with observers, they have objects passed to them. Surely there is some user data in there which can be used? I was specifically thinking of `user_id`

Comment: The way I am using teh observer is using def after_update(model) and then the code. So I don't see how objects can be passed to them apart from the object that is being observed. current_user is not part of the object being passed

Comment: Okay, my bad. Hopefully someone will have more of an idea than me :)

Comment: What's wrong with adding last_user column to the models (through concerns maybe to DRY) and tracking it's change?

Comment: Yeah that was what I have started to think about, although for now I am using the Thread approach, although not happy about it. My point still stands that I feel that functions such as current_user should be available in the model